# Adding Ricoh C4501 printer via command line - Installable options

Tags: macos, command-line, remote-desktop, printing

I need to deploy one Ricoh MFP to ~50 Mac users. I thus wan't to do this through ARD/CLI. I'm looking for the correct lpoption tags for the Ricoh MP C4501. I want to set the "Finisher" (SR3020) and "Option Tray" (Lower Paper Trays) in a cmd that can be distributed via ARD.

So far I can add the printer no problem... what I can't manage to do it set the installable options for it, here's where I'm up too:

```
lpadmin -p [PRINTER_NAME] -D [USER FRIENDLY DESCRIPTION] -L [PRINTER LOCATION] -E -v lpd://[PRINTERS DNS NAME] -P /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/RICOH\ Aficio\ MP\ C4501
```

Above is line one of the cmd and it works like a charm... below is each lpoption on its own line and as it doesn't work - I'm guessing I've got it wrong...

```
lpoptions -h lpd://[PRINTERS DNS NAME] -E -p [PRINTER_NAME] -l
lpoptions -h lpd://[PRINTERS DNS NAME] -E -p [PRINTER_NAME] -o media=A4 
lpoptions -h lpd://[PRINTERS DNS NAME] -E -p [PRINTER_NAME] -o OptionTray=Lower Paper Trays
lpoptions -h lpd://[PRINTERS DNS NAME] -E -p [PRINTER_NAME] -o finisher=Finisher SR3020
```

Basically - "OptionTray" and "Finisher" are complete guesses based on the naming in the PPD file itself... Ricoh wouldn't talk to me because we lease our boxes and the company we lease from... I'm still waiting for their help desk to respond...

I really hope someone can help...

Answer (score 1):

I know your post is old, but I was having the same issue with almost the same Ricoh Printer.

The finisher name looks like Finisher SR3020 in the OSX system preferences, but in the terminal it's a code name that you have to supply.

Type the following:

```
lpoptions -l
```

That will display all the options for your printer. One row will be titled:

```
Finisher/Finisher: *NotInstalled FinisherOne FinisherTwo Etc
```

The list of all available finishers will be displayed. My SR3020 was displayed as FinEUPHPOS. Thus I edited my script to be the following and it worked perfectly:

```
NAME="Printer Name"
DESCRIPTION="Printer Description"
LOCATION="Printer Location"
ADDRESS="printer.location.com"
PPD="RICOH Aficio MP 6001.gz" //printer driver file
FINISHER="FinEUPHPOS" //printer finisher name

lpadmin -p "$NAME" -D "$DESCRIPTION" -L "$LOCATION" -E -v lpd://"$ADDRESS" -P "/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/$PPD" -o "$FINISHER"
```

Answer (score 0):

Great work here folks. Here is the code I am using to add our copier, which is also a Ricoh. I've added the '-o printer-is-shared=false' option as this turns off that annoying check box. Another option, '-o auth-info-required=negotiate' I have left out as this printer doesn't require authentication through Active Directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Add MAD copier. Assumes driver and PPD are already installed.
lpadmin -p PC236X1 -D "MAD Copier" -L "C236" -E -v lpd://PC236X1.ONCAMPUS.LOCAL -P /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/RICOH\ Aficio\ MP\ 4002.gz -o finisher=FinKINGB -o OptionTray=2Cassette -o printer-is-shared=false
# cut out -o auth-info-required=negotiate as this doesn't need security
```